# Android Studio: which exactly type does Variant.buildType property have?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I'm studying an existing Android Studio project and came across the following code in the build.gradle file:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name
        //...
    }
}
```

I cannot understand which exactly type **variant.buildType** has and where I could look up the list of properties. I studied the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.3/com/android/build/api/variant/Variant which says that `buildType` has `String?` type, but it cannot be so because String doesn't have `name` property.
The documentation also says *"might be replaced with access to locked DSL object once ready"* about `buildType` property. I don't understand what it means but it seems to be the key point.
So the question is, what type does this `buildType` property actually have and how does all of this work?

Comment: The documentation you linked is for Gradle 7.3 (or maybe the Android plugin of that version). Which versions are you using?